# MS Clarity cpaturing unformated page when bluring info

Tags: css, angular, clarity, ms-clarity

I'm using Clarity in my Angular web app to capture usage metrics, and for privacy issues, i'm bluring the information on screen which is a Clarity feature, but when i do so, apge formatting goes bananas, with components on top of others, no margins a and etc, is there a solution for this, or a probable cause.

My app basically tree types of styling, a main style file, that sets colors and main classes styles, local files that defines some sub pages specifc styles , and component files , that define component specific styles. could this architecture choice be the reason for the formatting break in the captured sessions?

I tried remving the option to blurr info , and that solved the formatting issue, bu i need my recorded sessions to have blurred infor for privacy reasons.

Comment: please provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), else because of downvotes eventually this question will close soon.